# How can i share klov reports with other people?

Tags: java, mongodb

Klov reports are working fine. My question is how can i share klov reports with other users?

I have tried running on the local host but if i want share this report how can i ?

```
 ExtentKlovReporter klovReporter = new ExtentKlovReporter();

        klovReporter.initMongoDbConnection("localhost", 32017);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can share it by using your ipaddress. If suppose your ip address is 192.168.55.69, then other recipients can access it by "192.168.55.69:32017" (your ip  : port no).

you can share the report link directly, but it may ask the recipient to select project from drop down menu based on your klov version

Answer (score 1):

Actually there're several there're several options.

1. Run your tests on CI server (like Jenkins) and then publish it as HTML report;
2. Install an http server (IMHO the simplest is NGINX) and put your files inside, you can use a docker container and deploy it anywhere, locally on the cloud vm, on-prem server and so on.
3. Create an AWS S3 bucket (or alternatives on other clouds), allow hosting option and then upload your files.

And so, so on...